# jquery .inside()?

Tags: jquery, tags

I was wondering if it was possible to insert content inside html tags. So say you have a h4 tag:

```
<h4>Some Header</h4>
```

And you want the text to also be surrounded by a span with a class of "line". Like so:

```
<h4><span class="line">Some Header</span></h4>
```

I know about stuff like .after() but is there something like .inside() to do this with? \

Ok...I know I could do this manually, but in this situation it is out of the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('h4').contents().wrapAll('<span class="line" />');
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('h4').wrapInner('<span class="line" />');`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called $.wrapInner()

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
<h4>Some Header</h4>
```

and then:

```
$('h4').wrapInner('<span class="line" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

> The .wrapInner() function can take any
>   string or object that could be passed
>   to the $() factory function to specify
>   a DOM structure. This structure may be
>   nested several levels deep, but should
>   contain only one inmost element. The
>   structure will be wrapped around the
>   content of each of the elements in the
>   set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the existing content and wrap it (so that the `<h4>` has content wrapped with a `<span>` as shown), try [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/).